# UWP - Change app package name from command line using msbuild

Tags: msbuild, uwp, msbuild-task

Is there a way to change the package name when building W10 UWP apps with msbuid?

I'm running the following command:

```
msbuild my_project_name.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Which results to **my_project_name**_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug.appx

I would like to change **my_project_name** when building the package if possible?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered your same question in MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a676da01-f97c-498e-ba73-28c633da6d03/uwp-change-app-package-name-from-command-line-using-msbuild?forum=wpdevelop

It is possible by changing the "projectname" property through command. For example:

```
 msbuild /property:projectname=anewnameasyouwant D:\Customer's\CCombox\CCombox\CCombox.csproj /t:rebuild
```

And the result:
[image]
More details please see the switches section of  MSBuild Command-Line Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx